# What do the keywords future, async, await mean?

Tags: flutter

I want to know exactly what the future, async, await keywords mean, and why they are inter dependant on each other in flutter.

Comment: These videos may be helpful in understanding the concept: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUDOIAssBDs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyvTrXCDdYg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three are connected, the future is a class that can be filled with potential value or an error that comes from async, which runs asynchronously in your application.

font : https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures